# Expected Safari data directory does not exist

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Selenium 2.41, 
Mac_OSX = 10.8.5, 
Safari = 6.0.5

While launching Safari driver getting error message "The expected Safari data directory does not exist: /Users/null/Library/Safari"

After googling found out code in Safari extension classes is expecting  System.getenv("USER"),

```
if (Platform.MAC.is(current)) {
      return new File("/Users/" + System.getenv("USER"), "Library/Safari");
    }
```

Configured .bash_profile and launchd.conf  file, However this does not seem to fix the issue...

When i execute syso(System.getenv("USER"); in eclipse ide its still returning "null"

Could anyone please assist in resolving this issue

Thanks In advance

Answer (score 0):

That'w weird, I'm on mac and in terminal:

```
 echo $USER
```

gives my user.

Comment: Yes Eugene, echo $USER displays correct details. However when i try to launch safari driver through selenium. Its throwing below exception""The expected Safari data directory does not exist: /Users/null/Library/Safari". I wanted to override the default safari path.

Answer (score 0):

According to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html the correct property for your question would be

```
System.getProperty("user.name")
```

Also have a look at `System.getProperty("user.home")` (but note it could get messy under Windows when using Java 7 or older).